# From file to array of char(MFC)

Tags: c++, c, mfc, strtok

(I'm using Visual c++ 6.0 so I have no CString::Tokenize)
I have text file with the following text:

```
Conf1 Conf2 Conf3 Conf4
Conf5 Conf6 Conf7 Conf8
Conf9 Conf10 Conf11 Conf12
```

And I looking for the best way to insert the text into char[]

What I tried ( into CString str I have all the text from the file):

```
char *token;
char s[2]=" ";
token = strtok(str, s);   
while( token != NULL ) 
{
  myCharArray[I++]=token;    
  token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

But I cannot "catch" the next line (dont know how to know if "Conf4" include '\n')

Comment: Any reason you can't just use an `ifstream` and a `vector` of `string`s? It's not like VC++6 doesn't have a standard library.

Comment: Did you try `char s[]=" \n";` ?

Comment: Read the file line by line, then do the tokenization on each line separately.

Comment: user657267, Ok, how can I do it with vector and ifstream?

Comment: Michael Walz, yes I tried..stil not work

Comment: @EvyatarEvyatarr " \n" probably doesnt work, because in Windows lines are terminated by "\r\n". have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), libraryPtr) != NULL)
{
  if (str[0] != 0 && (str[strlen(str)-1] ='\n'))
    str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;

  char *token;
  char s[]=" ";
  token = strtok(str, s);   
  while( token != NULL ) 
  {
    myCharArray[I++]=strdup(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
  }
}
```